# How to set legend symbol type in javafx area chart

Tags: css, javafx

I needed to set legend symbol type as rectangle, circle and triangle for an area chart in javafx. When I set the chart symbol type it automatically updates the legend symbol too. I can't to set these two things separately. E.g. legend symbol  as triangle and chart symbol as circle. I use the following css to set these properties.

```
.chart-legend-item-symbol{
    -fx-background-radius: 5;
}//For circle legend symbol

.default-color0.chart-area-symbol {
    -fx-background-radius: 0;
}//For rectangle chart symbol
}
```

please help me to overcome this issue...